# Django, upload two files on one page

Tags: python, django

**model.py:**

```
class InJPG(models.Model):

    file_path = models.FileField(upload_to="media",unique=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from model import InJPG

def get_name(request):
    file1=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    file2=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    if file1.is_valid():
        file1.save()  
    if file2.is_valid():
        file2.save()

    return render(request,'files.html',{'file1':file1,'file2':file2})
```

**files.html**

```
 ...

{% block page %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{file1}}
        <button type="submit">upload file1</button>
    </form>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{file2}}
        <button type="submit">upload file2</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have web page, where I can upload two files `file1 and file2`

problem:
I can load one file at once only, page is refreshing when I am uploading first file.

I want to Load both files using one button. or two load buttons without refreshing second form.

I am using two forms because i want to separate webpage and use there card classes

Comment: You can't use two different forms on a single page and expect both of them to work while submitting one of them. You either have to combine the forms into one or do some js and ajax calls to separate the submission since django template will pass the data and refreshes the page on the first submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the files have to be passed to the same form as two separate inputs.

Try this:

```
{% block page %}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" required="True">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file1">
    <input type="file" name="file2">
  <button type="submit">Submit both files</button>
</form>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: got it, so one form for one page then. so what should I do ,when I want to add field file_name? normally i can use form from views.py and add in my models char field, but in this `<input type=file` i dont see any option to show filename

Comment: that will be another two inputs, having attribute type="text". e.g. <input type="text" name="file1_name">

Comment: I have one more question if I can ask, i am using one form but with my code , because i am using models.py/  when i am loading those two files when i am printing their names, it seems that both files are same. I am uloading file 1 and file 2 , but as result i am receiving two times file 2.  why? thanks

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question where you show your code.